# Rotation matrix in spherical coordinates

Tags: rotations, spherical-coordinates

When given arbitrary point on a unit sphere $a = (\theta, \phi)$ and an arbitrary axis $\vec{A}=(\Theta, \Phi)$, can we have an algebraic expression for $a_1=(\theta_1, \phi_1)$ which is a rotation of $a$ around $\vec{A}$ to the angle $\beta$?

Points and axes are not on the coordinate planes, values are not trivial: $\theta \neq 0$, $\phi \neq 0$, $\Theta \neq 0$, $\Phi \neq 0$, $\beta \neq 0$.

Can this be done without transformation through Cartesian? Otherwise the analytic form becomes too complicated. If there is a particular case for $\Phi \rightarrow 0$ ($\sin{\Phi} \approx \Phi$, but not for the other values) it is also fine.

Thanks

Comment: I find the exponential notation (ie in terms of the Lie group elements for the system in question) to be the most enlightening.

Answer (score 21):

I think what you might be looking for is [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). Using spherical coordinates:

Your arbitrary point on the unit sphere is:
$$
\mathbf{a} = (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta)
$$

Your arbitrary axis is represented by the unit vector:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{k}} = (\sin\Theta\cos\Phi, \sin\Theta\sin\Phi, \cos\Theta)
$$

Then the result of rotating $\mathbf{a}$ around $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ by the angle $\beta$, using the right-hand-rule, is given by

> $$
> \mathbf{b} = \cos\beta\,\mathbf{a} + \sin\beta\,(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \times \mathbf{a}) + (\hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot\mathbf{a})(1-\cos\beta)\,\hat{\mathbf{k}}
> $$

Of course, now $\mathbf{b}$'s Cartesian coordinates need to be converted to spherical:
$$
\tan\phi' = \frac{b_y}{b_x}
\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
\tan\theta' = \frac{\sqrt{b_x^2 + b_y^2}}{b_z}
$$
so that
$$
\mathbf{b} = (\sin\theta'\cos\phi', \sin\theta'\sin\phi', \cos\theta')
$$

The same article on Rodrigues' Formula also discusses a [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) of the rotation operation in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. The matrix representation is much cleaner, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Rotations in spherical coordinates are affine transformations so there isn't a matrix to represent this on the standard basis $(\theta,\phi)$, you'll need to introduce another coefficient here: $(\theta,\phi,1)$, the rotation matrix in the $\theta$ direction is then, for example, rotating by $\alpha$ is;
$R(\alpha) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \alpha \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

Comment: Ok, thanks, and what about the axis of rotation? shoudn't it go somehow into the matrix terms?

Answer (score 1):

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906095/rotating-a-point-in-spherical-coordinates-around-cartesian-axis/1847806#1847806) I explain how to deal when the rotation axis is one of the Cartesian axes.

For an abritrary rotation axis $\vec{A}=(\Theta,\Phi)$, using the same notations, the formula is
$$
(\theta', \phi') = (Q^{-1} \circ R_{\vec{A}}(\beta) \circ Q)(\theta,\phi)
$$
where the rotation operator $R_{\vec{A}}(\beta)$ is
$$
R_{\vec{A}}(\beta) = R_z(\Phi)R_y(\Theta)R_z(\beta){R_y(\Theta)}^\dagger{R_z(\Phi)}^\dagger
$$
("${}^\dagger$" is the notation for the conjugate transpose).