# Coordinate Matching of Sphere within a Sphere (Gloves)

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

Is there a mathematical formula to determine comparison matching of two spheres sharing the same center poibt but different axis?  Specific applications include celestial or terrestrial coordinate comparisons.

Example:  If one were to envision the Earth kverlaying Uranus.  Earth's axial tilt differs from Uranus, where Uranus has its polar coordinates "aimed" at an almost horizontal skew compared with Earth.

If one were to overlay these two globes (envision one centered within the other), their equatorial latitude line, and all latitude and longitude lines would form a type of "web" of lozenges where they intersected (crossed) ot given intervals.

For this formulation, one would know the polar cooriinates of both spheres (the x,y) as well as the equatorial and prime meridian planes of each.  Note:  for the sake if the formula, any selected longitude line (prime meridian) would be the differing starting reference logitude for each (degree zero line).

Having these known planes of reference, is it possible to use a formula to determine the two sets of coordinates for any desired point on the "surface" of these overlayed spheres?

Assume these spheres are static (i.e.  not rotating; being a snapshot of a specific date and time).

Example:  Assuming such a formula exists -- if I choose a desired coordinate of Sphere A (let's say Earth logitude 44.321 degrees west and latitude 39.789 degrees south).  What longitude and latitude of Sphere B (Uranus) intersects (overlays( at that point?

Comment: Perhaps rotation matrices will help

Comment: Yes, the two coordinate systems are related by a rotation. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019910/rotation-matrix-in-spherical-coordinates and http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/RotationSphericalCoordinates.html. You could also convert to Cartesian coordinates, rotate using [Rodrigues’ formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0sJrouJrTAhVHwFQKHdwwAigQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRodrigues%2527_rotation_formula&usg=AFQjCNG9W4SKXPIwa7Hnl8U59tbk8EzHBw) or some other way and convert back to spherical.