# Rotation matrix in three axis spherical coordinates

Tags: matrices, rotations, spherical-coordinates

Suppose I have two vectors on a unit sphere in spherical coordinates

$$ v_1 = [\theta_1,\phi_1,1]$$

$$ v_2 = [\theta_2,\phi_2,1]$$

I want to find a rotation matrix $R$ such that:

$$v_1' = R * v_1 = [0,0,1] $$

$$v_2' = R * v_2 = [\Theta,0,1] $$

Is it possible to construct a rotation matrix in spherical coordinates without converting to cartesian coordinates first?

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019910/rotation-matrix-in-spherical-coordinates) where one of the answers suggests a rotation matrix to rotate by $\alpha$ in one axis is:

$R(\alpha) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \alpha \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

But I'm struggling to adapt this for three-axis rotation.

Comment: I'm not sure it will be possible in the general case.  You've specified 12 constants and the matrix R has only 9 variables.  If you discarded the $v_2$ case it would be easy though.